# I can't set invisible a JFrame from a actionPerformed declared in an AbstractAction inner class, how to solve?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, inner-classes

I am developing this **MainWindows** class that extends a **SingleFrameApplication** abstract class that automatically provide a **JFrame**

When the **main()** method is executed it check if the user is logged in, if the user is not logged in, first show another **JFrame** windows implemented by the **LoginFrame** class. Here the user insert its username and password and can log in returning to my **MainWindows** (if the login is ok).

At this time this **MainWindows** class contains only a **LogOut** button, and the click event on this button is handled by the **actionPerformed** method definied inside an **AbstractAction** inner class. I want that, when this button is clicked, this **MainWindows** have to be setted as invisible and the **LoginFrame** windows appears in its place.

The problem is that, from here, seems that is impossible to set this **MainWindows** as invisible. Eclipse give me an error on this line:

```
mainFrame.setVisible(false);



package com.test.login;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class MainWindows extends SingleFrameApplication {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 880;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 440);


    private final Action actionLogOut = new AbstractAction() {
        {
            putValue(Action.NAME, ("LogOut"));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!");
            String[] args = null;
            launch(LoginFrame.class, args);
            mainFrame.setVisible(false);
        }
    };


    // First execute the LoginFrame class to open the login windows:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside: MainWindows() ---> main()");

        if(!(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("loggedIn"))){
            launch(LoginFrame.class, args);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside MainWindows ---> startup()");

        JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         // main JFrame that represents the Windows
        mainFrame.setTitle("My Appliction MainFrame");

        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);

        mainFrame.add(new JButton(actionLogOut));
        //mainFrame.add(new JButton("LogOut"));

        show(mainFrame);


    }

}
```

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: `Eclipse give me an error on this line:` but what kind of error ? please post the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

To access the current frame from your ActionListener use generic code to you don't need to access class variables. Something like:

```
publc void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
    window.setVisible(false);
}
```